# How does Java decide the type of a ternary conditional operator expression?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Can anyone explain this?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = 'A';
        int i = 0;
        boolean b = true;

        System.out.println(b ? c : i);
        System.out.println(b ? c : (char)i);

        System.out.println(b ? c : 0);
        System.out.println(b ? c : (char)0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 65
>   A
>   A
>   A

It sure looks strange from where I'm standing. I would have expected only `A`s to print out. And moreover: how come when I substitute `0` for `i` the output changes? The output seems to be the same for all values of `i`, not just `0`.

Comment: What behavior were you expecting to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification, about type conversion and promotion (see the text in bold)

> EVERY expression written in the Java programming language has a type that
>   can be deduced from the structure of the expression and the types of the literals,
>   variables, and methods mentioned in the expression. It is possible, however, to
>   write an expression in a context where the type of the expression is not appropriate.
>   In some cases, this leads to an error at compile time. In other cases, the context may
>   be able to accept a type that is related to the type of the expression; **as a convenience,
>   rather than requiring the programmer to indicate a type conversion explicitly, the
>   Java programming language performs an implicit conversion from the type of the
>   expression to a type acceptable for its surrounding context.**

The type conversion in your case that happens at compile time explains the output.

In the cases where `i` was involved, `c` has been promoted to integer.

In the cases where `0` was involved, it is treated as character and hence `c` remained as character.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to select apples vs oranges, you must promote one of them (the lesser one):

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = 'A';
    int i = 0;
    boolean b = true;

    System.out.println(b ? c : i);       // Promoted to int ---> 65
    System.out.println(b ? c : (char)i); // Not promoted ------> A (char vs char)

    System.out.println(b ? c : 0);       // Not promoted vs null/0
    System.out.println(b ? c : (char)0); // Not promoted vs char
  }
}
```

If there was a variable type such as `nibble` then you would not get a different output when selecting.

```
System.out.println(b ? c : (nibble)i); // I know there is no nibble. :)
                                       // nibble promotes to char.
                                       // I know... there is no nibble.
                                       //so, output is A
```