# ternary operator and primitive types

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I come across at this code, and I am puzzled why ternary operator is behaving this way, (I didn't find exact same question on stackoverflow, so bear with me )

Have a look at this code

```
public class TernaryOperatorTester{
 public static void main(String []args){
  Integer i1 = 8;
  Integer i2 = 8;
  byte b1 = 3; //OK
  byte b2 = 5 + 4; //OK
  byte b3 = i1 == i2 ? 4 : 8; //KO!
  byte b4 = i1 == i2 ? (byte)4 : 8; //OK!!, else part do not need cast!
  short s1 = i1 == i2 ? 4 : 8; //KO! similarly 
  short s2 = i1 == i2 ? (short)4 : 8;//OK!!,and again else part do not need  cast!
  }
}
```

first, what is returned in the ternary operator is literal value (it is not a expression is that is promoted to an int or other larger data types), - just like `b1`, and `b2`, so why `b3` is not OK with literal value?

second, even if there is explanation for `b3`, why `b4` is OK without cast in the else part of the expression ?

I put some other example with short data type, which has the same behavior.

thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: While it's not a precise duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332574

Comment: both are not duplicate! I am not taking about auto-boxing here.

Comment: The specification tells the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is determining its return types based on the "if" and "else" values.  When it sees a "4" as the "if" value, it assumes it is returning an int type.  If "4" is cast as a byte, the ternary operator knows that it should return a byte type.

You do not need to cast the "else" value because the ternary operator already knows its return type, and the "else" value fits the type.

Comment: and why we don't need cast when assigning value directly to b1 for example?  the ternary operator is returning a literal value.

Answer (score 0):

As for b3, an Integer is being assigned to a byte. Unboxing and narrow primitive conversion, do not go hand-to hand in a  implicit way.

Convert the Integer to an int, it will work or else type cast the Integer.